# Integration rules for ∫ x^x dx

Tags: calculus, power-series

I'm working on Project Euler, [problem 48](https://projecteuler.net/problem=48):

> The series, 1<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + ... + 10<sup>10</sup> = 10405071317.
>
> Find the last ten digits of the series, 1<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + ... + 1000<sup>1000</sup>.

This would be the equivalent of:
$$
f(n) = \sum_{i = 1} ^ n i^i
$$

The original question aside, it got me thinking. The rate of change from n to n+1 would be i^i, so if I could take the integral of i<sup>i</sup>, I could get a generalized formula for any given n. Upon plugging it into Wolfram Alpha, I got a monstrous expansion, but it said, "no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions". It's been years since I've taken calculus and I'm mostly a computer science guy to begin with, but is this premise sound? And if not, where did I go wrong?

Comment: 1. The integral approximates the sum, but doesn't equal it exactly.  2. The integral is a beast, with no nice value in terms of familiar functions.

Comment: In terms of actually solving the problem this is a red herring

Comment: I've used a completely unrelated method to solve the problem. This was just a curious thing.

Comment: The function is difficult / impossible to integrate using pen and paper. And the integral is related to the sum, but it's not exactly the same. For instance, the difference between the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac1i$ and the integral $\int_1^n\frac1xdx$ closes in on what is  called the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Likewise, the difference between your sum and your integral is non-zero, although I summer in your car that difference diverges.

Answer (score 1):

There is no closed form for this integral, but there might be special integrals solving this, which can be only calculated numerically.

Comment: The derivation of functions works in many cases, but finding an antiderivate is often impossible, and even if it is possible, it may be extremely hard.